# Is it variable initialization failure?

Tags: c++, variables, variable-initialization

Being following the book "Programming Principles and Practice Using C++" by Bjarne Stroustrup for learning C++ right from the very basics. It all proved good until this happened...

```
int main()
{
      cout << "Please enter your first name and age\n";
      string first_name = "???"; // string variable
      int age = -1; // integer variable
      cin >> first_name >> age; // read a string and then integer
      cout << "Hello, " << first_name << " (age " << age << ")\n";
}
```

Now, as the above code *(under the section Input and Types, Chapter 2)* suggests, it outputs a string which familiarizes us to the *name* and *age* of a person. As I have initialized the *integer variable* ***age*** to **-1**, the program must return **-1** to the monitor if I, in case by mistake, input a *string value* into ***age***. The issue is that it just won't happen in my computer. I have tried and compiled and run the program 19 times (I do remember it...) but the result is always the same: it outputs **0 instead of -1**.

For e.g. if I enter `ABCXYZ 16`, then the output will be a nice and simple **Hello, ABCXYZ (age 16)**. But if the input was `16 ABCXYZ`, then the output comes out to be **Hello, ABCXYZ (age 0)**, which I expected to be **Hello, ABCXYZ (age *-1*)** as the string `ABCXYZ` won't be read into ***age*** (it is an *integer variable*) and thus give out the initialized value because it wasn't overwritten.

Any idea?

P.S.: I'm using Code:Blocks with GCC - 8.1.0

Comment: How old is the edition you are reading? This detail changed in c++11. Please consider to rtfm (read the fine manual). For example here:https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt

Comment: The old behaviour always seemed more logical to me. Not sure why it was changed.

Comment: Remove the unnecessary code and text from your question. `int age = -1; std::cin>>age; std::cout<<age;` would suffice.

Comment: @john same here, I am really puzzled what was the motivation. Code that was UB before and no longer is UB now is very likely still wrong

Comment: @idclev463035818 It says Second edition. The cover page mentions that the book uses C++11 **and** C++14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::istream& operator>>(int &value)` calls `std::num_get::get()` internally. From [cppreference std::num_get::get()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get) the behavior changed in c++11.

Having `v` to denote the variable we read into, until c++11 we had:

> - If an error occurs, v is left unchanged.

However since c++11:

> - If the conversion function fails to convert the entire field, the
>     value ​0​ is stored in v
> - If the conversion function results in a
>     positive or negative value too large to fit in the type of v which is
>     a signed integer type, the most positive or negative representable
>     value is stored in v, respectively
> - If the conversion function results
>     in a value not to fit in the type of v which is an unsigned integer
>     type, the most positive representable value is stored in v.

You are compiling using a compiler and C++ standard library configured to be compatible with a standard after c++11, so when `std::cin` fails to read the field, the value of `0` is stored into `age`.

Comment: so `>>` can't be used?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is isolated to the `>>` operator, where it fails to convert your string input into an integer (which is expected, as `std::cin >> x` handles expected input, from the type you define for `x`), and hence returns a 0, irrespective of whatever value you initialized the integer variable with.

This was done since C++ 11 as Kamil mentioned, and conforming to previous standards, the value would have been left unchanged and would return a -1 for your case.

You can check if `cin` fails or passes for the same to draw a conclusion yourself:

```cpp
int main() 
{
      int age = -1; 
      std::cin >> age;
      if(cin) 
      std::cout << age; 
}
```

If you enter an integer (as expected from the type of `age`) you'd get the output for the value of age you initialized it to, else if you enter a string, cin will fail (and its failbit will be triggered, resulting in false) and nothing will be displayed, in accordance with the if-statement above.

Comment: Right, `cin` is failing. So, as @KamilCuk said, the `>>` operator can't be used to fulfill the purpose that I mentioned?